# Are there guides on how to build arcade games for StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

I am interested in building a mini-game and figure StarCraft 2's arcade might be a fun way to get started. Some quick Googling has not turned up any any tutorials on where to get started. I know I can use the included map editor, but are there any introductory tutorials to creating StarCraft 2 arcade games available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SC2Mapster](http://www.sc2mapster.com/) is a site dedicated to map-making for Starcraft 2.

Their [tutorials sub-forum](http://www.sc2mapster.com/forums/resources/tutorials/) has tons of mini-guides describing how to do various things in the map editor. Note that that sub-forum is *not* the appropriate place to ask questions about how to do things; for that, go to the sub-forum specifically related to the kind of thing you have a question about (triggers, terrain, UI, cinematics, etc).

Answer (score 6):

Blizzard has published [arcade map making tutorials](http://battle.net/sc2/en/game/maps-and-mods/) for people like you. Hope it will work for you.